# App Crashes when I connect an IBOutlet in a ViewController managed by a UITabBar

Tags: objective-c

OK So I have an app that has a button that loads in a new view modally. This new view has a tab bar and is inserting subviews(with their own Xib Files) according to its tab bar item tag number. Everything works great, however when I connect an IBOutlet inside one of these subviews with Interface Builder it crashes the app when i go to that tab. The IBOutlet is a UITextField and is being populated through its filesOwner (that same xibs .h and .m files). I am getting no warnings when building. I have researched this for about a week now and have tried changing the files owner class inside of interface builder, I've tried to delete the views and recreate them and still nothing, I've tried to delete and rewrite my IBOutlets and delete and reconnect them in IB and still nothing.

BELOW IS MY CODE THAT ADDS THE SUBVIEWS ACCORDING TO TAG NUMBERS:

```
-(void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item{
if (item.tag == 2) {
    if (classDescriptionsViewController_ == nil) {

        classDescriptionsViewController_ = [[UIViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"secondViewController" bundle:nil];


    }
    [self.view insertSubview:classDescriptionsViewController_.view belowSubview:tabBar];

    if (currentViewController_ != nil && currentViewController_ != classDescriptionsViewController_) {
       [currentViewController_.view removeFromSuperview];

    }currentViewController_ = classDescriptionsViewController_;

}
 if (item.tag == 1) {
    [currentViewController_.view removeFromSuperview];
     currentViewController_ = nil;
}
if (item.tag == 3) {
    if (raceDescriptionsViewController_ == nil) {
        self.raceDescriptionsViewController = [[UIViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"raceDescriptionsViewController" bundle:nil];
    }
    [self.view insertSubview:raceDescriptionsViewController_.view belowSubview:tabBar];
    if (currentViewController_ != nil && currentViewController_ != raceDescriptionsViewController_) {
        [currentViewController_.view removeFromSuperview];
    }currentViewController_ = raceDescriptionsViewController_;
}}
```

BELOW IS MY CODE THAT ADDS THE TEXT TO THE UITEXTFIELD (THE IBOUTLET):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.textField.text = @"PLEASE WORK!";
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out... I had to set the delegate for that viewcontroller.